# Difference between eclipse sirius and epsilon

Tags: model-driven-development, eclipse-sirius

Can someone help me?
I would like to know the main differences between the eclipse sirius and epsilon to develop M2M solutions or another MDE approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sirius is mainly for developing Editors for models that conform to ECore metamodels. Epsilon is a framework for model management tasks: transformation, validation, merging, cote/text generation, etc.

If you want to write model to model (M2M) transformations you can use Epsilon. If you want to provide a custom editor for your models (e.g. not a tree editor) use Sirius.